# Nop commerce How To handle Allowed Quantity for purchasing product

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am developing the nop commerce store.

I have Two questions for the same.

1 ) I have a requirement where i want user to purchase the product from the specified Quantities. I.E. I want T-Shirts to be bought in one of  these Quantities. 10 , 20 , 35 , 55.

I am Aware with the Minimum Order Quantity Text box. But how can i only allow user to select from the specified quantities ?

2 ) if someone wants to order 6 different sizes of the same shirt, how can i combine the sizing so that they only have to order X total pieces, and not X of each size ? Here X is the minimum order quantity that user need to purchase.

I am using Nop Commerce 3.50.

Comment: about your 1st question, you need to customize product detail page and instead of quantity text box use dropdown box and disply your allowed qty. and pass that Dropdown selected value in product Qty Field, by this you can get your result.

Comment: About 2nd question, there is no such method for that, you need to make different order for each size because if you try to archive this by customizing then it take long time and may be not exactly works as per your need because, you need to handle all place like order, billing, invoice generation and cart page etc...so i suggest make different order for each size.

Comment: @VinitPatel Thanks for your suggestions. The issue about first option is i only want this for certain categories not for all products on store. So What could be best option for this ?

Comment: for add 1 falg in product that fix qty or not, set it true in that product in which you want to add qty from dropdown and check condition on view page that if flag is true then disply dropdown else disply regular textbox...this solve your problem.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that i found for one of the two questions i had. The 2nd one seems to be not possible for now.

1 ) There is a field called "Allowed Quantities" when editing a product.  It's located below the minimum and maximum quantities fields.  Just enter in the values separated by commas and it'll give the user a drop down list of quantity options.

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: That makes sense, but has anyone found a way to make this list more robust?  I want to sell in qty's of 3 but need my allowed qty's to go up into the thousands...